# Unable to issue identity in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to issue an identity to a participant that already exists in the network.

```
 return this.bizNetworkConnection.connect(this.cardname)
     .then((result) => {
         let email = 'user@gmail.com',
             username = email.split('@')[0];

         this.businessNetworkDefinition = result;

         return this.bizNetworkConnection.issueIdentity('org.test.Person#user@gmail.com', username);
     })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(`userID = ${result.userID}`);
        console.log(`userSecret = ${result.userSecret}`);

     })
```

I expect that I will see the userID and the userSecret logged on the console but I am getting errors as described below.

Following the developer tutorial on their documents:

1. If I use the card name for PeerAdmin@hlfv1 on the connect function above, I get the error. "Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Missing \"chaincodeId\" parameter in the proposal request"
2. If I use the card name for admin@tutorial-network on the connect function above, I get the error "fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]"

For option 1, I know the network name is missing in the given card, whie option 2 means that the admin has no rights to issue an identity. However, I cannot seem to find any documentation directing me on how to use either to achieve my objective. Any help is highly welcome.

While I have listed the javascript code I am using to achieve the same, I would not mind if anyone can explain what I am missing using the composer cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue.html

you would definitely use the `admin@tutorial-network` card, as PeerAdmin does not have authority to issue identities (admin does).

Did you already do: 1) a `composer card import -f networkadmin.card` (per the tutorial)  ? 2) a `composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network` to use the card (now in the card store) and thereby populate the admin's credentials (certificate/private key).

Only at that point would admin be recognised as the identity to issue further identities. Is it possible you spun up a new dockerized CA server at some stage since you did the import etc ?

What happens if you issue a `test` identity through the command line (using admin@tutorial-network? Does it fail)

Comment: When I use `composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network`, I do get a successful listing of the network, composer version and "Command succeeded". Infact, I have used the card to access registries via Javascript. The only problem is that I cannot issue identities for now.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul. There's a comment that you deleted about deleting .composer directories before reinstalling composer again and registering the PeerAdmin etc. I did that and it worked. I had been initially using 0.15.1 before shifting to 0.16.0 without deleting .composer* directories from home directory.

Comment: One question though, while following the tutorial, the cli commands work well but the javascript ones don't. For example, after issuing the identity successfully using javascript its hard to ping because we don't have a card created like in the cli. Besides, how does one generate the certificates that are used to bind an identity in the code? The tutorial kind of skips these points. Could you help?

Comment: On 015.1 -> 0.16.0 - I see - that's fine. (as opposed to since 0.15.2, it will clear out cleanly, upon a `composer card delete` cmd (per card). On issuing cards using APIs, you should use the card import in the APIs -> this may help you (the answer near the bottom that is - but obviously you would create a new card to connect to hlfv1 etc etc) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393096/nodejs-test-hyperledger-composer-v0-15-fails-with-error-card-not-found-peeradm

Comment: I installed version 0.19 (never had a 0.16 before), and yet I'm getting Authorization failure error (although with code 20) when I'm trying to issue an identity.

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: thanks - I've updated it in the answer now. Thumbs_up.