# Hyperledger Composer module local_connection.json when deployed on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, hyperledger-composer

I have a hyperledger composer project that runs smoothly on localhost but I tried to deployed it to Google Cloud Compute Engine and does not work properly.

The project is divided in two parts: a composer network, and a nodejs backend to interact with the network. T

I followed the developer and deploy to single organization tutoriales from Composer site.

The nodejs server handles the registration and sign in logic and expose a rest api to interact with the client side. This is my code:

index.js

```
//post call to register graduate on the network
app.post('/api/registerGraduate', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Creando cuenta graduado");
    var graduateRut = req.body.graduaterut;
    var cardId = req.body.cardid;
    var firstName = req.body.firstname;
    var lastName = req.body.lastname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phonenumber;

    network.registerGraduate(cardId, graduateRut, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber)
      .then((response) => {
       //return error if error in response
        if (response.error != null) {
            res.json({
            error: response.error
            });
          } else {
          //else return success
          res.json({
          success: response
                });
            }
      });    
});
```

network.js

```
   registerGraduate: async function (cardId, graduateRut,firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber) {
      try {


    //connect as admin
    businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
    await businessNetworkConnection.connect('admin@degree');

    //get the factory for the business network
    factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();

    //create graduate participant
    const graduate = factory.newResource(namespace, 'Graduate', graduateRut);
    graduate.firstName = firstName;
    graduate.lastName = lastName;
    graduate.email = email;
    graduate.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;


    //add graduate participant
    const participantRegistry = await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Graduate');
    await participantRegistry.add(graduate);

    //issue identity
    const identity = await businessNetworkConnection.issueIdentity(namespace + '.Graduate#' + graduateRut, cardId);

    //import card for identity
    await importCardForIdentity(cardId, identity);

    //disconnect
    await businessNetworkConnection.disconnect('admin@degree');

    return true;
  }
  catch(err) {
    //print and return error
    console.log(err);
    var error = {};
    error.error = err.message;
    return error;
  }

},
```

I'm testing the rest api with postman. The error I'm getting back is `"error": "Cannot find module './local_connection.json'"` but that happens only the first time I send the post request. The second time the error is `Error: Failed to add object with ID '166438715' in collection with ID 'Participant:org.degree.ucsd.University' as the object already exists`.

Apparently despite the error is writing the data to the blockchain, but if I try to get the data I get an error stating that the `cardid` is not found.

So, what did I miss? If it works on localhost but not on a Google VM, is it the authentication? How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT!

importCardForIdentity function:

```
async function importCardForIdentity(cardName, identity) {

  //use admin connection
  adminConnection = new AdminConnection();
  businessNetworkName = 'degree';

  //declare metadata
  const metadata = {
      userName: identity.userID,
      version: 1,
      enrollmentSecret: identity.userSecret,
      businessNetwork: businessNetworkName
  };

  //get connectionProfile from json, create Idcard
  const connectionProfile = require('./local_connection.json');
  const card = new IdCard(metadata, connectionProfile);

  //import card
  await adminConnection.importCard(cardName, card);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 2nd error reported, is because (as you indicate), the participant is already created.

The real issue is trying to locate the newly issued 'graduateRut' business network card ('not found') from your client REST API or postman - in your current setup it would look for this on the same client under $HOME/.composer - is this on a different node to your nodeJS backend?

Also is your `ImportCardForIdentity` function something like shown here ?

[Unable to issue identity card using Hyperledger Composer Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282506/unable-to-issue-identity-card-using-hyperledger-composer-javascript-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. I added the importCardForIdentity function to my question. In the answer in the link you provided, there's no declared variable for the `connectionProfile` parameter.

And yes, my network and nodejs backend are running on the same VM.

Comment: np. so eg.  - let connectionProfile = config.get('connectionProfile');` (using config as required module and setup) -  or setting it this way (example here -> https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-composer-api-for-managing-business-network-cards-80f215db27f7)  - or obviously the way you're using it. The issue then is the 'path' to the file to load the JS object - have you tried providing the full path to the connection.json `require` ?

Comment: the article from medium helped me. It works now! Thank you!